# In R, Sift Through a Dataframe for N Consecutive Rows of Data (a "Window"), Then do a Function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to read a raw data output .csv file containing 10's of thousands of rows. The rows are mostly not filled with meaningful data, but every once in a while, a cluster of N (usually 5 or so) rows shows up that contains the meaningful data. I want to sift through the rows, and when I encounter these clusters, write the maximum of the cluster to a file that is continuously updated with these maximums.

Here's an example of the data:

[screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFedK.png)

The second column is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Best way to get help is to post small reproducible example here, in line, and not link to external sites. It helps to show sample input, expected output and any other code.

Comment: Thanks!
The sample input is a massive .csv file; do you know what the markdown syntax is for pasting in a snippet of the data for two columns? If you can assist with that, I will gladly add it, as well as the expected or desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The `rle` function lets you scan a vector and get lengths of sequences. The hand-waving answer is to scan for sequences of `rle(vector>0)$values` associated with  `rle(vector>0)$lengths is > 5`.

We cannot do very much with pictures of object viewers. So to give a tested, *code-containing* answer we need *code-produced* data that can be pasted into a console session. In this case you probably what sequences of values that age non-zeroFind a section of your dataframe that I'm assuming is named `dfrm` that appears interesting to you and post the output of `dput(dfrm[ rownames(dfrm) %in% i:j , ])` where i and j are rownames several rows above and belwo the area of interest. We can then show you how to use `rle` and `cumsum` and `seq` to build a selection vector for the rows of interest.

Comment: Thanks, I will do some work with learning the rle function. However, I am starting from scratch with the raw output file from third party software, which provides the raw data to be converted into a dataframe. No code exists yet; I am mostly looking for some jumping-off point to begin coding, after which I will post the code.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't need help reading the datafile  into R but rather processing the dataframe from `read.csv` and you named it `dfrm`. Post output of `dput( dfrm[ n:(n+30), c(c1, c2)] )` where n is a rownumber before the start of a sequence and c1 and c2 are the column numbers (or names) of interest.

Comment: I think another way to put it would have been a request in creating a peak detection algorithm to analyze a large data set.